# Realm.io / Dagger / Databinding in the same project

Tags: android, realm, dagger-2, android-databinding

I am having issues with compiling my project after I added Realm.io as a dependency via gradle. The generated files created by dagger and databinding can not be found. If I remove realm.io the app compiles correctly.

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "com.foo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.2.0'
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.2.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.4.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.0'
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.85.1'

compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1"
apt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:1.0-rc4'
}
```

[image: Error]

I see that Realm is also generating files and maybe the compilers are not playing nice together. Any ideas on how to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, Realm's annotation processor is creating proxy classes which are also compiled during a build. In the screenshot it looks like the errors are related to other classes than Realm. Does your app build if you remove Realm?

Comment: Yes, i remove realm the app builds fine

Answer (score 2):

I see that you also received the error:

> No setter found for field goalInfo

Make sure the field names are the same as the getters and setters. Do not prepend "m" to the field names. Example:

```
@RealmClass
public Goal extends RealmObject {
    //private String mGoalInfo;
    private String goalInfo;

    public String getGoalInfo() {
        return goalInfo;
    }

    public void setGoalInfo(String goalInfo) {
        this.goalInfo = goalInfo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Databinding works with RealmObjects](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/realm-1-2-0-android-data-binding-1dc06822287f#.hfw42yj72), but you have to implement Observable.

```
public class Post extends RealmObject implements Observable {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;

    private String text;

    @Ignore
    private transient PropertyChangeRegistry mCallbacks;

    @Bindable
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
        if(!isValid()) { // !isManaged() in Realm 2.0
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.id);
        }
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        if(!isValid()) { // !isManaged() in Realm 2.0
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.text);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void addOnPropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChangedCallback callback) {
        if (mCallbacks == null) {
            mCallbacks = new PropertyChangeRegistry();
        }
        mCallbacks.add(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChangedCallback callback) {
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.remove(callback);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Notifies listeners that all properties of this instance have changed.
     */
    public synchronized void notifyChange() {
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.notifyCallbacks(this, 0, null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Notifies listeners that a specific property has changed. The getter for the property
     * that changes should be marked with {@link Bindable} to generate a field in
     * <code>BR</code> to be used as <code>fieldId</code>.
     *
     * @param fieldId The generated BR id for the Bindable field.
     */
    public void notifyPropertyChanged(int fieldId) {
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.notifyCallbacks(this, fieldId, null);
        }
    }
}
```

And Dagger + Databinding can break each other, for which you need to add

```
apt 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0' // dagger + databind workaround
```

Comment: Not working. It shows same error Package doesn't exists

Comment: @LuvnishMonga that probably means you have some error in your code somewhere

Comment: Code is working fine. I am only using Databinding and Realm. 
When my model class extends to RealmObject then it shows the same error which issue @Darussian is facing. When I implemented your code then It shows me same error.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce When should we use `implements Observable`, `implements RealmBaseObservable`, `implements Observable, RealmBaseObservable`?

Comment: What's a `RealmBaseObservable`? However, the `RealmDataBinding` interface was added to support listening for managed objects

Answer (score 1):

Realm, Dagger2 and Databinding are all working in my project.

The difference is:

I'm using android gradle plugin 1.5.0 and enable databinding by following configuration.

```
android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    ...
}
```

And I don't have

```
apt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:1.0-rc4'
```

in dependencies.

Whole working project is here: https://github.com/zaki50/realm_template

Comment: After update android gradle plugin to 2.0.0 and realm to 0.88.3, can you build success?

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to implement the RealmModel interface and add an annotation @RealmClass to the class instead of extending RealmObject. This lets you extends BaseObservable however it is still not working.

You get a databinding error: package mypackage.databinding does not exist

See this issue on github: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2716